# I had input and target normalized, but network output exceeds the range

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I normalized both input and target data into the range [0,1].
And I'm using ReLU as an activation function at all layers.
However, my network output exceeds 1. How is it possible?

Comment: Please give more details

Comment: My network is Unet and data is images. I converted all images into HSV color map and normalized H channel by dividing 360. S and V channels are normalized into the range [0,1] automatically when converted into HSV. And I was checking if my h channel of network output exceeds 1 and it turned out I have over 1 value for the network. I think that the output could not exceed the range theoretically. I don't get it.

Comment: Why not? Outputs are weighted sums of inputs. 0.7 + 0.5 = 1.2, the inputs are in the range [0, 1] but the output is not...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.